# Instance property, return a different instance per thread to avoid concurrency issues

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

Update: I've rewritten the question after some investigation on my own

I'm updating an existing class `(ClassA)` to be thread-safe. The same instance of this calls is going to be used in multiple threads (hence the refactor to become thread safe). Now this class has a property returning an object `(ObjectB)` that is not thread-safe. I would like the instance of the class to return the same value as much a possible, as long as it is used in the same thread.

Therefore I would like to use a `ConcurrentDictionary<int,ClassB>` to avoid the same instance to be returned on different threads. This way, I can contain the instances of `ClassB` within a specific instance of `ClassA`, but still return a different instance of `ClassB` for each thread to void concurrency issues.

Code example:

```
public class ClassA
{
  private ConcurrentDictionary<int, ClassB> _objectB = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, ClassB>();

  public ClassB ObjectB
  {
    get
    {
      return _objectB.GetOrAdd(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, (k) => new ClassB());
    }
  }
}
```

The above code makes sure the _objectB.Value is filled in a thread-safe way when requested, and reuses the same instance of ClassB as long as it is used within the same synchronizationcontext.

- Is this a correct way of doing this?
- Is there something wrong with it?
- Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`ThreadLocal<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadlocal-1) class. This class provides a thread-local storage of data. The value returned for the `Value` property is specific for the thread on which the property is accessed. Example:

```
public class ClassA
{
    private static ThreadLocal<ClassB> _objectB = new ThreadLocal<ClassB>();

    public ClassB ObjectB => _objectB.Value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, however my issue seems to be a bit more complicated than this. I'm afraid what I want to accomplish cannot be done

Comment: @PaulVrugt that's usually the case with multithreading.